# Selection sorting a type list (compile-time)

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

This question has the `tuple_selection_sort<>` template that sorts the variadic template of a tuple using a comparator (any template taking two types that has a `value` data member of type `bool`).

If the following tuple...

```
// sizeof:    1,   4,    1,      8,    1,     4
std::tuple<char, int, char, double, char, float>
```

Is sorted with a comparator that sorts based on type size (descending), we would get:

```
// sizeof:      8,   4,     4,    1,    1,    1
std::tuple<double, int, float, char, char, char>
```

### Refresher on the simple selection sort

This is a simple implementation of a selection sort on which the template-meta-programming version is based:

```
template <class T, class Comparator>
void selection_sort( std::vector<T>& v, Comparator c )
{
    for ( std::vector<T>::size_type i{ 0 }, sz{ v.size() }; i < sz; ++i )
    {
        for ( std::vector<T>::size_type j{ i + 1 }; j < sz; ++j )
        {
            if ( c( v[ i ], v[ j ] ) )
            {
                using std::swap;
                swap( v[ i ], v[ j ] );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Selection sort runs in \$O(n^2)\$. However, it was chosen for very simple reasons:

- Simple to implement.
- Common usage instances of `std::tuple<>` do not have many types. Thus, compile-time performance shouldn't become an issue.

### Implementation

Swapping two types inside a `std::tuple<>`:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

// swap types at index i and index j in the template argument tuple
template <std::size_t i, std::size_t j, class Tuple>
class tuple_element_swap
{
    template <class IndexSequence>
    struct tuple_element_swap_impl;

    template <std::size_t... indices>
    struct tuple_element_swap_impl<std::index_sequence<indices...>>
    {
        using type = std::tuple
        <
            std::tuple_element_t
            <
                indices != i && indices != j ? indices : indices == i ? j : i, Tuple
            >...
        >;
    };

public:
    using type = typename tuple_element_swap_impl
    <
        std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value>
    >::type;
};
```

The selection sort template:

```
// selection sort template argument tuple's variadic template's types
template <template <class, class> class Comparator, class Tuple>
class tuple_selection_sort
{
    // selection sort's "loop"
    template <std::size_t i, std::size_t j, std::size_t tuple_size, class LoopTuple>
    struct tuple_selection_sort_impl
    {
        // this is done until we have compared every element in the type list
        using tuple_type = std::conditional_t
        <
            Comparator
            <
                std::tuple_element_t<i, LoopTuple>,
                std::tuple_element_t<j, LoopTuple>
            >::value,
            typename tuple_element_swap<i, j, LoopTuple>::type, // true: swap(i, j)
            LoopTuple                                           // false: do nothing
        >;

        using type = typename tuple_selection_sort_impl // recurse until j == tuple_size
        <
            i, j + 1, tuple_size, tuple_type // using the modified tuple
        >::type;
    };

    template <std::size_t i, std::size_t tuple_size, class LoopTuple>
    struct tuple_selection_sort_impl<i, tuple_size, tuple_size, LoopTuple>
    {
        // once j == tuple_size, we increment i and start j at i + 1 and recurse
        using type = typename tuple_selection_sort_impl
        <
            i + 1, i + 2, tuple_size, LoopTuple
        >::type;
    };

    template <std::size_t j, std::size_t tuple_size, class LoopTuple>
    struct tuple_selection_sort_impl<tuple_size, j, tuple_size, LoopTuple>
    {
        // once i == tuple_size, we know that every element has been compared
        using type = LoopTuple;
    };

public:
    using type = typename tuple_selection_sort_impl
    <
        0, 1, std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value, Tuple
    >::type;
};
```

### Sample usage

```
template <class T, class U>
struct descending
    : std::conditional_t<( sizeof( U ) > sizeof( T ) ), std::true_type, std::false_type>
{};

int main()
{
    using input_tuple_t = std::tuple<char, int, char, double, char, float>;
    using expected_tuple_t = std::tuple<double, int, float, char, char, char>;
    using result_tuple_t = tuple_selection_sort<descending, input_tuple_t>::type;

    static_assert( std::is_same<expected_tuple_t, result_tuple_t>::value , "!" );
}
```

Comment: So what's the problem/question? Does it work? Is this a stable sort? (do you want a stable sort?)  What are use cases?

Comment: @Walter I put down a sample program, so yes, it works. It doesn't matter if it's stable for the end goal. The use case is as follows: `sizeof( std::tuple<char, int, char> == 12`, but `sizeof( std::tuple<int, char, char> )` is 8. Thus sorting the types in descending order saves memory.

Comment: @Walter I plan on using this to provider some sort of `tuple_wrapper<>` to keep memory usage down while maintaining usage as if the types were unsorted.

Comment: The stability of the sort may matter if there are types with the same size

Comment: @OlzhasZhumabek I generate a lookup table so that types are always indexed into properly. Before sorting, I index the types so that `std::tuple<char, int>` becomes `std::tuple<indexed<0, char>, indexed<1, int>>`, from there I generate a compile-time map.

Comment: Which compiler was used when writing the **tuple_selection_sort<>** and supporting structs? I compiled the code with MS-VS 14 and MS-VS 17 and received error C1001.

Answer (score 6):

I recommend a naming style that uses `CamelCase` for template parameters and `snake_case` (only) for plain old variables and functions, so that the reader can tell at a glance if something is a template parameter. For example, in the code that follows, you use `indices` as the name of a parameter pack; where I would name that pack `Is` (`Is` being the plural of `I`, and `I` being the natural name for a template parameter of type `int` just as `i` is the natural name for a plain old variable of type `int`).

I recommend a whitespace style that is much more compact than what you've got. I think your uncuddled `<` brackets make reading hard for both the human reader and (I would think) for the IDE. When you write

```
using type = std::tuple
```

I (and the IDE?) expect "hey, you're missing a semicolon!" whereas the actual diagnosis is "the line continues on the next source line, with an angle bracket." You wouldn't write

```
int value = sqrt
(
    pow(2, 10)
)+1;
```

would you? So how is it acceptable to write

```
using type = typename tuple_element_swap_impl
<
    std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value>
>::type;
```

?

```
// swap types at index i and index j in the template argument tuple
template <std::size_t i, std::size_t j, class Tuple>
class tuple_element_swap
{
    template <class IndexSequence>
    struct tuple_element_swap_impl;

    template <std::size_t... indices>
    struct tuple_element_swap_impl<std::index_sequence<indices...>>
    {
        using type = std::tuple
        <
            std::tuple_element_t
            <
                indices != i && indices != j ? indices : indices == i ? j : i, Tuple
            >...
        >;
    };

public:
    using type = typename tuple_element_swap_impl
    <
        std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value>
    >::type;
};
```

Purely by applying my naming and whitespace rules, we get

```
// swap types at index I and index J in the template argument Tuple
template<size_t I, size_t J, class Tuple>
class tuple_element_swap {
    template<class>
    struct tuple_element_swap_impl;

    template<size_t... Is>
    struct tuple_element_swap_impl<std::index_sequence<Is...>> {
        using type = std::tuple<
            std::tuple_element_t<
                Is != I && Is != J ? Is : Is == I ? J : I, Tuple
            >...
        >;
    };

public:
    using type = typename tuple_element_swap_impl<
        std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value>
    >::type;
};
```

And we can rewrite the expression `Is != I && Is != J ? Is : Is == I ? J : I` as simply `Is == I ? J : Is == J ? I : Is` — which is both cleaner *and* shorter.

In C++17, you could use `std::tuple_size_v<Tuple>` in place of `std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value`. That wouldn't be any more performant — in fact it would be a minor *harm* to compile-time performance — but it would be a little shorter in terms of readability.

---

EDITED TO ADD:

Okay, I've looked at the sort part now, too, a little bit.

I notice that you're using the equivalent of

```
if (condition) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

right here:

```
template <class T, class U>
struct descending
    : std::conditional_t<( sizeof( U ) > sizeof( T ) ), std::true_type, std::false_type>
{};
```

That can be written more compactly in C++14 as

```
template<class T, class U>
struct descending : std::bool_constant<sizeof(T) < sizeof(U)> {};
```

or in C++11 as

```
template<class T, class U>
struct descending : std::integral_constant<bool, sizeof(T) < sizeof(U)> {};
```

Notice that your sort uses the comparator *backwards!* You named the comparator `descending`, which is correct for what your sort algorithm does; but in reality your comparator is a lifted version of `std::less`, a.k.a. "ascending" (when passed to `std::sort`)! You should probably reverse the sense in which your sort algorithm uses the comparator, and then reverse the sense of your comparator. That is,

```
template<class T, class U>  // analogous to std::less
struct ascending : std::bool_constant<(sizeof(T) < sizeof(U))> {};

template<class T, class U>  // analogous to std::greater
struct descending : std::bool_constant<(sizeof(T) > sizeof(U))> {};
```

---

This code screams out at me for [SCARY-fication](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2018/07/09/scary-metafunctions/), or what Odin Holmes calls the "Rule of Chiel." Rather than instantiating new struct types for `std::conditional<true, int, float>`, `std::conditional<false, float, double>`, and so on, let's just instantiate *two* concrete types — `conditional_<true>` and `conditional_<false>` — and use type aliases for everything else.

Taking your current code, you'd make two substitutions. Instead of

```
template<class T, class U>
struct descending : std::bool_constant<sizeof(T) < sizeof(U)> {};
```

you'd write

```
template<bool B>
struct conditional_ {
    template<class T, class> using type = T;
};
template<>
struct conditional_<false> {
    template<class, class U> using type = U;
};

template<class T, class U>
using descending = conditional_<sizeof(T) < sizeof(U)>;
```

And then instead of

```
template <std::size_t i, std::size_t j, std::size_t tuple_size, class LoopTuple>
struct tuple_selection_sort_impl
{
    // this is done until we have compared every element in the type list
    using tuple_type = std::conditional_t
    <
        Comparator
        <
            std::tuple_element_t<i, LoopTuple>,
            std::tuple_element_t<j, LoopTuple>
        >::value,
        typename tuple_element_swap<i, j, LoopTuple>::type, // true: swap(i, j)
        LoopTuple                                           // false: do nothing
    >;

    using type = typename tuple_selection_sort_impl // recurse until j == tuple_size
    <
        i, j + 1, tuple_size, tuple_type // using the modified tuple
    >::type;
};
```

you'd write

```
template<size_t I, size_t J, size_t N, class LoopTuple>
struct tuple_selection_sort_impl {
    using NextLoopTuple = typename Comparator<
        std::tuple_element_t<I, LoopTuple>,
        std::tuple_element_t<J, LoopTuple>
    >::template type<
        typename tuple_element_swap<I, J, LoopTuple>::type,
        LoopTuple
    >;
    using type = typename tuple_selection_sort_impl<I, J+1, N, NextLoopTuple>::type;
};
```

You could perform the same transformation on `tuple_element_swap`; that is, instead of writing `typename tuple_element_swap<I, J, LoopTuple>::type` above, you could write `typename tuple_element_swap<I, J>::template type<LoopTuple>`. This again cuts down on unnecessary type instantiations.

As to whether any of this SCARY-fication actually matters to your compile times in practice, I don't know, you'd have to benchmark it. (For example, by running your sort on a whole bunch of very long and not-identical inputs.) For your single 6-element example that compiles in under a second, of course none of this matters, except for getting comfortable with the idiom.

---

Notice that I renamed your snake_case template parameter `tuple_size` to `N`. This not only flags it for the reader as a template parameter, but also makes the code *significantly* less confusing, since you do use some instantiations of `std::tuple_size` (a *class template*) sprinkled in among your references to `tuple_size` (an *integer constant*). Using different names for these different entities helps the reader understand what's going on. Additionally, the reader is already familiar with the runtime idea of "`i` looping up to `n` and then stopping," so the idea of `I` looping up to `N` and then stopping is immediately accessible in a way that it wasn't accessible when the name of `N` wasn't `N`.

---

EDITED AGAIN TO ADD: I actually tried out a [complete rewrite](https://godbolt.org/z/SaZM0D) into "SCARY" style, and compilation with Clang got drastically *slower*. Maybe I'm doing something wrong, or maybe I've misunderstood the advice that I was trying to pass on. :/  In any event, please benchmark before committing to any of my advice above!

The only thing that did noticeably improve compile time in practice was to replace your repeated use of `std::tuple_element_t` with a bare-bones compiler-intrinsic implementation [as described by Louis Dionne in late 2015](https://ldionne.com/2015/11/29/efficient-parameter-pack-indexing/):

```
template<size_t, class> struct nth_;
template<size_t I, class... Ts>
struct nth_<I, std::tuple<Ts...>> {
    using type = __type_pack_element<I, Ts...>;
};
```

Comment: ThisIsNotCamelCase, camelCaseHasTheFirstLetterOfTheFirstWordLowerCase.

Comment: [SomeCamelsHaveTwoHumps.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wild_Bactrian_camel)

Comment: Lol, true. My point is I think there's technically another name for ThisTypeOfCase. I think It's called CapitalCase. I'm being really nit picky though.

Comment: @Chipster ThisTypeOfCaseIsCalledPascalCase.